# Incorrect results in tic tac toe game enumerator

Tags: haskell

The following code should evaluate every possible game in tic tac toe and return the results as a list

```
data Piece = Naught | Cross deriving (Show, Eq)
data Result = Win | Lose | Draw deriving (Show, Eq)
type Board = Array Integer (Maybe Piece)

emptyBoard :: Board
evaluateBoard :: Board -> (Maybe Result)
allPossibleMoves :: Board -> [Board]

walkPaths :: Bool -> Board -> [Result]
walkPaths inv b = 
    if result /= Nothing
        then [fromJust result]
        else concat $ map (walkPaths (not inv)) (allPossibleMoves $ invertBoard b)
    where 
        result = if inv then invertResult evald else evald
        evald = evaluateBoard b 

allGamesResults = walkPaths False emptyBoard
```

This is giving me (wins/loss for first to move):

- Total: **255168**
- Wins: **77904**
- Lose: **131184**
- Draw: **46080**

Providing these results are correct (I can't find any data to verify mine with), why doesn't the first to move have more wins?

**UPDATE:** 
Source code can be found [here](http://hpaste.org/47784)

Comment: I think the bug can't be found without additional code (`evaluateBoard`, `allPossibleMoves`, `invertBoard`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *scree* from #haskell on freenode for the answer:

```
if result /= Nothing
    then [fromJust result]
    else concat $ map (walkPaths (not inv)) (map invertBoard $ allPossibleMoves b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first player to move has more options to choose from, since the board is empty, and there are more "bad" options than "good" ones available. So, the first player will lose more often if all possible cases are considered.